# Funcoes com parametros em linguagem c

Tags: c, c++

Preciso de ajuda para resolver o seguinte problema:

"Escreva uma função que recebe um arranjo de **inteiros** como parâmetro  e devolve o índice do maior elemento do arranjo. Ex : `int intMax(int *a, int tamanho)`"

Fiz uma parte do código  e ele faz o que foi pedido, só que não da forma que foi pedida:

```
int recebeArray(){
  int mtrx[5];
  int count, maior;

  for(count=0; count<5; count++){
    printf("Digite um numero \n");
    scanf("%d",&mtrx[count]);

    if(mtrx[count] > mtrx[count-1]){        
      maior=mtrx[count];
    }           
  }

  printf("O maior numero e' : %d",maior);
}

int main(){
  recebeArray();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa percorrer todos os elementos do vetor, armazenando em uma variável auxiliar o índice que contém o maior valor já encontrado, por exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int intMax( int *a, int tamanho )
{
    int i, max = 0;
    for( i = 1; i < tamanho; i++ )
        if( a[i] > a[max] )
            max = i;
    return max;
}

int main( void )
{
    int foobar[8] = { 4, 10, 2, 13, 3, 7, 1, 0 };
    int i = intMax( foobar, 8 );
    printf( "foobar[%d] = %d\n", i, foobar[i] );
    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
foobar[3] = 13
```

Comment: Não seria melhor o `i` do `for` começar logo em `1` ?

Comment: @Isac: Você está certo! Não é necessário varrer a *array* a partir do primeiro elemento (`i = 0`), a varredura pode começar a partir do segundo elemento (`i = 1`), caso ele exista.

Comment: @Isac: Realmente, se você considera o primeiro elemento como maior atualmente, não faz sentido passar por ele novamente.